# How to map Nginx http response header?

Tags: nginx

I tried several configs but seems to not work, like...

```
map $http_x_litespeed_cache_control $nocacheheader {
    default      0;
    no-cache   1;
    }
```

```
map $upstream_http_x_litespeed_cache_control $nocacheheader {
    default      0;
    no-cache   1;
    }
```

```
map $sent_http_x_litespeed_cache_control $nocacheheader {
    default      0;
    no-cache   1;
    }
```

Page is still cached.
What is the correct format?

My HTTP response header:
`x-litespeed-cache-control no-cache`

Comment: How are you using `$nocacheheader`?

Comment: I just don't want to cache a page if that header is present.
In addition to my current mapping/rule. https://add.pics/image/kGjD

Comment: Sorry I mis-read your comment, I'm using it like this: 
`fastcgi_no_cache   $nocacheheader $nocachecookie $nocacheuri;`
`fastcgi_cache_bypass   $nocacheheader $nocachecookie $nocacheuri;`